# Clear default selected Value `Bootstrap Select2`

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

I am using `bootstrap select2` and i need to handle this select so that default selected value that is `null` shall be cleared on selecting other options.

**HTML code**

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple="" name="maritalstatus[]" id="marital-status">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Does Not Matter</option>
    <option value="unmarried">Unmarried</option>
    <option value="divorce">Divorced</option>
    <option value="widow">Widowed</option>
    <option value="awaited-divorce">Awaiting Divorce</option>
</select>
```

**JSCode**

```
$("select").select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    containerCssClass: ':all:',
    dropdownCssClass: 'no-search',
    allowClear: true,
});
```

**UI**

[image]

Now as per UI, if i select any of the options other than `Does Not Matter`, then `Does Not Matter` shall be cleared always.

**Rule:**

- Does not Matter option can not exist with any of the other options.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to solve with below solution..

```
removeDefaultSelect2Value: function() {
  const selectIDs = "#id1, #id2";
  $(selectIDs).on("select2:select", function(e) {
    var $el = $(this);
    var data = e.params.data;
    //console.log(data.element);
    if (data.id === "") {
      $(this).select2("val", 0, true);
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $el
          .next("span")
          .find(
            'li[title="Does Not Matter"] .select2-selection__choice__remove'
          )
          .click();
      }, 10);
    }
});
```